# c# class how to reference in .cs file for website

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I'm new in programming.  I've followed the steps in the book "Pro asp.net 4 in c#2010" to create 2 classes.

Now I try to use this class on a webpage.  In the .cs file I added using "DBComponent;" but Visual Studio says "The type or namespace name 'DBComponent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

What did I forget?

If i try to add the compiled dll under 'references' i get the error:
The type 'DBComponent.EventDetails' in 'D:_Web\OSWeb\DBComponent\DBComponent\EventDetails.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'DBComponent.EventDetails' in 'D:_Web\OSWeb\DBComponent\DBComponent\bin\Debug\DBComponent.dll'. Using the type defined in 'D:_Web\OSWeb\DBComponent\DBComponent\EventDetails.cs'.

This is what I've done:

1. Create a new empty website 'OSWeb' in VS
2. On top of this solution I clicked right and choosed: Add > new Project > Visual C# > Windows > Class library: name: DBComponent and I stored in D:_Web\OSWeb\DBcomponent
3. List item

   I created 2 cs files (EventDB.cs and EventDetails.cs)

my events.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace DBComponent
{
    public class EventDB
    {
        private string connStr;
        
        public EventDB()
        {...}
        
        public EventDB(string connectionString)
        {...}
        
        public int InsertEvent(EventDetails evd)
        {...}
    }
}
```

This is my eventdetails.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace DBComponent
{
    public class EventDetails
    {
        private int eventId;
        private string eventName1;
        public int EventId { get { return eventId; } set { eventId = value; } }
        public string EventName1 { get { return eventName1; } set { eventName1 = value; } }
        public EventDetails(int eventId, string eventName1)
        {
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.eventName1 = eventName1;
        }
        public EventDetails() { }
    }
}
```

Now I create a new webpage (this is the .cs file of this webpage) (events.aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DBComponent;  => here is the error
public partial class events : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private EventDB db = new EventDB(); => here is the same error
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In your website project, have you added a project reference to your class library?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/996358/332733, also -1 for not researching how namespaces work first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:
right click on your web project and click in properties, then click en references. remove the reference of your class, close this windows. Verify in the Bin folder from you proyect, yours references (should not be the reference has been removed.). Next, you open again the project properties and add your class library.

(before adding the reference should be sure that the class library compiles correctly.)

sorry for my english

Comment: your welcome!. if you served the response, you should mark it as correct. Greetings!